# browsing internet via proxy in epiphany

Tags: linux, gnome

Any idea how to set up proxy in epiphany? Something like in firefox's preferences/advanced/network/connection?

edit:
I guess it can be done in gnome settings? But won't this be system wide? I would like ONLY epiphany to use proxy and firefox and other browsers don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Gnome socks proxy](http://blog.agdunn.net/?p=107) (instead of within epiphany).  This will cause you all sorts of headaches with other apps, though (like apt, etc.)

> Tell Gnome to use your Tunnel
>
> You can tell all applications on your
>   system to use this tunnel through
>   Gnome’s network-proxy interface. It is
>   located under
>   System>Preferences>Network Proxy. You
>   can set up the SOCKS proxy in the
>   Network Proxy and apply the settings
>   system wide

Answer (score 2):

You can try environment variables, if your gnome version allows you to set the proxy to "detect automatically" or "system" or something similiar. Then programs should respect the `http_proxy` variable and you can try

```
$ http_proxy=yourproxy epiphany
```

Comment: it doesn't work for me

Comment: Can you try to use ``http_proxy=http://proxy:port`` with ``http://`` before the proxy? I currently cannot test here, but it may work then.

Answer (score 1):

Can't be done the way you want according to the [Epiphany documentation](http://live.gnome.org/Epiphany/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#head-b1468629650bebf35d91fda8555f21fa22940267)

Perhaps you have to do it the other way round / find a browser other than Epiphany to use  the proxy, which is not what you want but the best I can think of (dillo seems a rather recherche web browser that  you aare probably not using and it will use a proxy if you set it up in your ~/.dillo/dillorc configuration file).

Comment: Where on that documentation page are you referring to?